# Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT in Kubernetes cluster on DigitalOcean

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, containers, digital-ocean

I'm using DigitalOcean for deployment. I have NestJs app and KeyDb(Redis alternative) containers.
I folowed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-docker-compose-workflow-to-kubernetes) to convert my Docker Compose file to k8s. After successfull deployment on the logs for NestJs I'm getting an error:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN keydb
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:170:41)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:631:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:598:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN keydb
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
```

My dockerfile:

```
# Start with the official Node.js 18 Alpine image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and yarn.lock files
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

# Install dependencies including 'devDependencies' for building the app
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN yarn build

# Expose the port your app will run on
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to start the app
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

My Docker-Compose File looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  keydb:
    image: eqalpha/keydb
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - nestjs-keydb-net
    restart: always

  nestjs-app:
    image: dmytroye/node-kubernetes
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    depends_on:
      - keydb
    environment:
      - KEYDB_HOST=keydb
      - KEYDB_PORT=6379
    networks:
      - nestjs-keydb-net
    restart: always
    

networks:
  nestjs-keydb-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Looks like my NestJs app can't connect to KeyDb, and I just don't know why, and how can I handle this. If you need more code or info - do not hesitate to ping me about it.

Just in case, my Redis constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    this.client = new Redis({
      host: 'keydb',
      port: 6379,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved via configuring an app to call KeyDb via namespaces:

```
constructor() {
this.client = new Redis({
  host: 'keydb.namespace_name.svc.cluster.local',
  port: 6379,
});}
```